# Does a SOA Services Box/ESB (API) can reside on the same server than my ERP system or it should reside on a separate infrastructure physically?

Tags: architecture, soa, restful-architecture

I want to build an API (services box/ESB) with the purpose of interacting with our internal systems. (ERPs, Product Information Management System, OMS, etc.)

I have the opportunity to do it on the same architecture of one of ERPs. It's financially wise but I fear it could be bitting us in the butt later.

My other option is to build it on a standalone infrastructure that will be completely independent.

Based on SOA principle and architecture best practices, should I build it on our ERP server or in a standalone cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In recent times,there have emerged two trends for ESB ,one being federated ESB ,other being singular ESB.

If it's a single ESB which is being planned ahead, the concept of Separation of Concerns fits in well here . orchestration ,choreography,service discoverability become better when ESB is independently sanitised .IMHO,keep it on a separate server ,so not only one system ,many systems can reuse the service.

Answer (score 0):

I like Udi Dahan's explanation that an ESB is like ethernet. You can't point to it and say "here's my ethernet." It's lower-level infrastructure that basically runs everywhere. Everything else builds on top of it.

If it's centralized, then you're using a message broker rather than a bus. This architecture is analogous to a hub-and-spoke network, with the message broker being the hub.